# PHP Laravel: Trait not found

Tags: php, laravel

I have some trouble with namespace and use.

I get this error: "Trait 'Billing\BillingInterface' not found"

These are the files in my Laravel application:

Billing.php

```
namespace Billing\BillingInterface;

interface BillingInterface
{
    public function charge($data);
    public function subscribe($data);
    public function cancel($data);
    public function resume($data);
}
```

PaymentController.php

```
use Billing\BillingInterface;

class PaymentsController extends BaseController
{
    use BillingInterface;

    public function __construct(BillingPlatform $BillingProvider)
    {
        $this->BillingProvider = $BillingProvider;
    }
}
```

How to i use use and namespace properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BillingInterface` is an `interface` not a `trait`. Thus it can't find the non existent trait

Also you have an interface called `BillingInterface` in a namespace called `Billing\BillingInterface`, the fully qualified name of the interface is: `\Billing\BillingInterface\BillingInterface`

Perhaps you mean

```
use Billing\BillingInterface\BillingInterface;
// I am not sure what namespace BillingPlatform is in, 
// just assuming it's in Billing.
use Billing\BillingPlatform;

class PaymentsController extends BaseController implements BillingInterface
{
    public function __construct(BillingPlatform $BillingProvider)
    {
        $this->BillingProvider = $BillingProvider;
    }

    // Implement BillingInterface methods
}
```

**Or to use it as a trait.**

```
namespace Billing;

trait BillingTrait
{
    public function charge($data) { /* ... */ }
    public function subscribe($data) { /* ... */ }
    public function cancel($data) { /* ... */ }
    public function resume($data) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Again the modified `PaymentsController`, but with fully qualifies names.

```
class PaymentsController extends BaseController
{
    // use the fully qualified name
    use \Billing\BillingTrait;

    // I am not sure what namespace BillingPlatform is in, 
    // just assuming it's in billing.
    public function __construct(
        \Billing\BillingPlatform $BillingProvider
    ) {
        $this->BillingProvider = $BillingProvider;
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont want to implement to the controller.

Comment: @andershagbard Then you will have to make a trait that implements the methods of BillingInterface. However traits are not types in PHP nor can they implement an iterface so you will lose type hierarchy as in `PaymentsController` is not a `BillingInterface`. Alternativly and probably the best approach would be to inject the controller with an object that can do billing. Perhaps that is the point of the `BillingPlatform` but I can't be sure.

Comment: Isn't that what I'm doing in my construct function?

Comment: @andershagbard If that is what a `BillingPlatform` is then yes. See the updated answer that includes a trait implementation. Also I have fully qualified all the namespaces.