# Trait 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesResources' not found

Tags: laravel-5

[image]

Anyone familiar with this error i'm getting?

Please help thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Laravel: Trait not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27625707/php-laravel-trait-not-found)

Comment: Please show your `Controller.php`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you are using Laravel 5.3 do the following:

From the upgrade guides: The AuthorizesResources Trait

The AuthorizesResources trait has been merged with the AuthorizesRequests trait. You should remove the AuthorizesResources trait from your app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php file.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the problem is with your version of laravel/framework.. Running `composer update` should pull in the latest version (which is 5.2.39). If that doesn't work for you, then I'm not sure what else you can do. Perhaps try `composer self-update` before you do it.

If you run composer info laravel/framework the 4th line should show you the latest version from packagist, which is: 5.2.39.

Edit: You could try and clear your package cache: `composer clearcache`

Answer (score 0):

Does Laravel connect to database? I had this error and it was caused by a wrong database configuration in .env file.
Try these settings in .env file:
1. **Open .env file in your project's folder.** 
Don't touch the .env.example file found in the same location as it's an example of .env default configuration. If something goes wrong with your .env file, you can copy and paste the configuration from the .env.example file to .env.

2. **Change the following 4 lines to your own configuration:**

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=forge
DB_USERNAME=forge
DB_PASSWORD=
```

**DB_DATABASE** It's the name of your database. Should be 'forge' by default or check your phpMyAdmin to determine which database you need to use. You can create a new database if you're an administrator of phpMyAdmin ('root' user).
**DB_USERNAME** This is your username when you log in to phpMyAdmin. Should be 'forge' by default.
**DB_PASSWORD** Your phpMyAdmin should not be protected with password by default. The password is set later manually. In case you'll set the password, add it to DB_PASSWORD line after you do so.
3. **Save the modified .env file and restart the Apache server.**

Try to access your webpage again. 
This worked for me. I hope it's gonna work for you, too.

P.S. If it doesn't work, check if the .env configuration is *right* for *you*. Or use `php artisan config:clear` to clear cache.