# Laravel using laflux

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I followed the instructions here to install laflux https://github.com/LaFlux/Laflux

I get the error Trait 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesResources' not found

I have done composer update, composer clear-cache

Below is my controller.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

Anyone has any idea how to fix this? Thank you !

Comment: What version of laravel are you using ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trait not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37625522/trait-illuminate-foundation-auth-access-authorizesresources-not-found) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trait 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesResources' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37625522/trait-illuminate-foundation-auth-access-authorizesresources-not-found)

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.3 , however if you see above, my controller does not have the AuthorizesResources does it is not a duplicate of other questions.

Comment: maybe you could have used in some other controller, I would have suggested you to check for it in other controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it, it's caused my my httpd-vhosts wasn't set correctly.
Thanks everyone !

Comment: What did you do to fix it?

Comment: @warmwhisky It has been some time back, I don't really remember but do check your vhosts if they are pointing to the correct path.